# index greater than GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS (while it's actually lower than the HW limit)

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm having a problem running my app on my phone, while it runs fine on the emulator. I'm using OPENGLES 2.0 for Android and the problem seems to be in OpenGL. The following errors are basically repeated every time I draw a frame:

```
gles_state_set_error_internal:63: GLES error info:<program> could not be made part of current state. <program> is not linked GLES a_norm-1
gles_state_set_error_internal:62: GLES ctx: 0x7fa2596008, error code:0x502
gles_state_set_error_internal:63: GLES error info:<index> is greater than or equal to GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS
```

My phone is an Allview P5 Energy running Android 5.1, kernel 3.10.65+
The emulator that runs my code well is a Google Nexus 4, 4.2.2. API 17.

As the error code suggests I may be trying to write too many attributes per vertex, so I checked with the following code snippet the maximum amount of attributes supported by my (emulated) hardware:

```
IntBuffer max = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
 GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS,max);
 System.err.println("GLES MAX IS"+max.get(0));
```

For the emulator this gives 29, and for my real phone 16. Ok 16 is less but as you can see in my shader, I only use 3 attributes, and 3<16... The shaders are as follows:

```
  public static final String vertexLightTexture = "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;"+  // A constant representing the combined model/view/projection matrix.
            "uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix;"+         // A constant representing the combined model/view matrix.
            "attribute vec4 a_Position;"+       // Per-vertex position information we will pass in.
            "attribute vec3 a_Normal;"+         // Per-vertex normal information we will pass in.
            "attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate;"+  // Per-vertex texture coordinate information we will pass in.
            "varying vec3 v_Position;"+         // This will be passed into the fragment shader.
            "varying vec3 v_Normal;"+           // This will be passed into the fragment shader.
            "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;"+    // This will be passed into the fragment shader.
            "void main()"+
            "{"+
                "v_Position = vec3(u_MVMatrix * a_Position);"+ // Transform the vertex into eye space.
                "v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;"+ // Pass through the texture coordinate.
                "v_Normal = vec3(u_MVMatrix * vec4(a_Normal, 0.0));"+ // Transform the normal's orientation into eye space.
                "gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;"+ // regular position
            "}";

    public static final String fragmentLightTexture = "precision mediump float;"+
            "uniform vec3 u_LightPos;"+     // The position of the light in eye space.
            "uniform sampler2D s_Texture;"+ // The input texture.
            "varying vec3 v_Position;"+     // Interpolated position for this fragment
            "varying vec3 v_Normal;"+       // Interpolated normal for this fragment
            "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;"+// Interpolated texture coordinate per fragment.\n" +
            "void main()"+
            "{"+
                "float distance = length(u_LightPos - v_Position);"+ // Will be used for attenuation
                "vec3 lightVector = normalize(u_LightPos - v_Position);" +// Get a lighting direction vector from the light to the vertex
                "float diffuse = max(dot(v_Normal, lightVector), 0.0);" + // dot product for the illumination angle.
                "diffuse = diffuse * (1.5 / (1.0 + (distance/8)));\n" + // Attenuation.
                "diffuse = diffuse + 0.2;" + // ambient light
                "gl_FragColor = (diffuse * texture2D(s_Texture, v_TexCoordinate));" +// Multiply the color by the diffuse illumination level and texture value to get final output color.
            "}";
```

The code I use to pass data into the shader is the following (first for initialization):

```
int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, Shaders.vertexLightTexture);
    int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,Shaders.fragmentLightTexture);
    // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);

    // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);

    // creates OpenGL ES program executables
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
```

In the init method I also put the vertex, normal and texture coordinates through buffers in the GPU memory. Then for each frame I execute this code and basically for each data element I try to write I get the aforementioned errors. This is the draw method called for each frame:

```
 public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix, float[] mvMatrix, float[] lightPosition){
        // group all wall elements at once
        // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        // Get handle to shape's transformation matrix]
        int mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "u_MVPMatrix");
        System.err.println("GLES MVPMatrix" + mMVPMatrixHandle);
        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

        // Get handle to shape's transformation matrix]
        int mMVMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "u_MVMatrix");
        System.err.println("GLES MVMatrix" + mMVMatrixHandle);
        // Apply the view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvMatrix, 0);

        // Get handle to textures locations
        int mSamplerLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "s_Texture");
        System.err.println("GLES s_tex" + mSamplerLoc);

        // Set the active texture unit to texture unit 0.
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);

        // Bind the texture to this unit.
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);
        // Set the sampler texture unit to 0, where we have saved the texture.
        GLES20.glUniform1i(mSamplerLoc, 0);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_Position");
        System.err.println("GLES a_pos" + mPositionHandle);
        // Use the buffered data from GPU memory
        int vertexStride = COORDINATES_PER_VERTEX * 4;
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferIndex);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, 0);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        int mNormalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_Normal");
        System.err.println("GLES a_norm" + mNormalHandle);
        // Use the buffered data from GPU memory
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBufferIndex);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mNormalHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mNormalHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, 0);

        // Get handle to texture coordinates location
        int mTextureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "a_TexCoordinate" );
        System.err.println("GLES a_tex" + mTextureCoordinateHandle);
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBufferIndex);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        // Clear the currently bound buffer (so future OpenGL calls do not use this buffer).
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        // Pass in the light position in eye space.
        int mLightPosHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "u_LightPos");
        System.err.println("GLES u_light" + mLightPosHandle);
        GLES20.glUniform3f(mLightPosHandle, lightPosition[0], lightPosition[1], lightPosition[2]);

        // Draw the Square
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferIndex);
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,numberOfIndices,GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);
        // Clear the currently bound buffer (so future OpenGL calls do not use this buffer).
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mNormalHandle);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTextureCoordinateHandle);
}
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful, I've tried a lot already, like using a simple cube model instead of my high-poly figure I'm trying to draw, but nothing worked so far to get rid of the errors on the phone. On the emulator any model is drawn well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the fragment shader. Somehow the hardware in the phone couldn't handle dividing by 8, it had to be 8.0, so it would know it's a float.

```
public static final String fragmentLightTexture = "precision mediump float;"+
        "uniform vec3 u_LightPos;"+     // The position of the light in eye space.
        "uniform sampler2D s_Texture;"+ // The input texture.
        "varying vec3 v_Position;"+     // Interpolated position for this fragment
        "varying vec3 v_Normal;"+       // Interpolated normal for this fragment
        "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;"+// Interpolated texture coordinate per fragment.\n" +
        "void main()"+
        "{"+
            "float distance = length(u_LightPos - v_Position);"+ // Will be used for attenuation
            "vec3 lightVector = normalize(u_LightPos - v_Position);" +// Get a lighting direction vector from the light to the vertex
            "float diffuse = max(dot(v_Normal, lightVector), 0.0);" + // dot product for the illumination angle.
            "diffuse = diffuse * (1.5 / (1.0 + (distance/8.0)));\n" + // Attenuation.
            "diffuse = diffuse + 0.2;" + // ambient light
            "gl_FragColor = (diffuse * texture2D(s_Texture, v_TexCoordinate));" +// Multiply the color by the diffuse illumination level and texture value to get final output color.
        "}";
```

I have to say the error message of GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS wasn't helpful at all and really threw me off to search in the wrong direction.

Comment: Why not start with the first error message rather than the second, which said that the program wasn't linked correctly? Always debug the first error first ... later errors are often a result of earlier errors propagating.

Comment: Good point looking back at it I understand that it was more telling. The fact that it ran on the emulator made me assume the program was correct and the link failed due to the MAX_ATTRIBS